# Is it possible to name an enum constant "name" in Kotlin?

Tags: enums, kotlin

Is there any workaround to make it possible to name a Kotlin enum constant `name`?

This works in Java:

```
public enum Dummy {
    name
}
```

This throws `Conflicting declarations: enum entry name, public final val name: String` in Kotlin

```
enum class Dummy {
    name
}
```

Comment: Currently I don't think it's possible... `name` is `final`, `@JvmName` cannot save you.

Comment: Addition: due to the same problem it is also impossible to name an enum constant `ordinal`.

Comment: @Moira keep in mind that you can access static members through class instances!

Comment: Why don't you adhere to the convention of using uppercase for enum constants?

Comment: Due to this funny Java rule, given `enum X { A, B, C }` you can legally say `X c = X.A.B.C;` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. Every enum member has two properties: name (string) and ordinal (int). So, there is conflict with names.

And remember. Even if you could do that you should not. Enums should be UPPERCASE (my mistake, can be also CamelCase, check first comment) and breaking this rule can be very distracting for other developers working with your code.

More information in Kotlin docs:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html

Comment: Just a minor remark on the naming conventions: the official style guide accepts upper camel-case enum entry names as well: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#property-names